# Fetcing dynamically added fields in forms - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

i have some data that will be added in hidden input fields inside a form.

Now since i'm using symfony2 forms those fields don't get submitted.
i.e. `$form->getData()` does not get data from those fields.

how do i get data from those dynamically added (hidden) input fields as well?

Comment: Why do you need those hidden fields? What problem are you trying to solve using them?

Comment: i need to pass some numbers, rather an array of integers (add them through js) depending on which i will i have to perform some specific task inside the form submit action before binding the form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch post values in context of a form type:

```
$postData = $request->request->get('form_name');
$name_value = $postData['title'];
```

Fetch post values not in context of a form type (maybe this is what you need):

```
$data = $request->request->all();
$name = $data['input_name'];
```